# Which dot matrix printer is recommend for ubuntu (10.04 or +)?

Tags: printing, epson

I need to buy a better dot-matrix printer and I am currently using the **Epson LX-300** (like IBM pro printer)

I found in resellers:

> Epson LX-300 II, FX-890, FX-2190, LQ-2090 OKI ML1120, ML320, ML620,
>   ML621

Comment: It might be worthwhile to mention how you use your printer, what you usually print, and how much you print each month.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Ubuntu Wiki** lists Epson Printers that have been tested on the currently supported version of Ubuntu.

As you are not fixed on one model you can browse through these by [**clicking on this link**](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportComponentsPrintersEpson)

**Make sure your printer is compatible**

More help is available here at the [**Linux Foundation**](http://www.openprinting.org/printers) where you can enter the name and model of the Printer and it will tell you if its compatible

I did a little bit of research and fear your options maybe be limited, you may also find [this link](http://www.tomshardware.co.uk/forum/237338-38-epson-matrix-printer-driver-ubuntu) useful